# Como hacer la configuracion para redireccionar de http hacia https ya con VHost o .htaccess

Tags: laravel, debian, apache2, ssl, vps

Actualmente tengo una aplicación montada de pruebas en un vps de debian y ya instale los certificados SSL y al parecer los instale de forma adecuada ya que si pongo https://mipagina.com.org  me redireccionar al sitio de forma segura y se ve el candado en el navegador pero si pongo http://mipagina.com.org, mipagina.com.org o [www.mipagina.com.org](http://www.mipagina.com.org) me sale un mensaje de Not Found pero lo que quiero es que me redireccione en automático a la liga segura (https).

Codigo del VHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    ServerName mipagina.com.org
    ServerAlias www.mipagina.com.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ProyectoLaravel/public/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/xxx/yyy/zakuhpy_com_mx.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/xxx/yyy/HSSL-5fcbe7ac62c9b.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/xxx/yyy/zakuhpy_com_mx.crt

ServerName mipagina.com.org
ServerAlias www.mipagina.com.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

</VirtualHost>
```

Código del .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mipagina.com.org/$1 [R,L]
```

Alguna cuestión de porque no se hace el re direccionamiento.

Answer (score 0):

Para forzar la redirección https con el siguiente código el .htaccess te sirve:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Con eso te redirecciona a https://wwww.

Ahora bien, en tu servidor DNS debes de crear el subdominio con un registro A, que apunte a la misma IP que tu dominio raíz (Debes hacer esto primero, de lo contrario el portal se volverá inaccesible).

Si estas en un ambiente local, modifica los registro en el archivo Host.

Suerte!